# Set fixed background full size html doesnt work

Tags: html

I try to show background on my html website,

```
 <body background="img/Free V Bucks Codes, Background.jpg">
```

This code works

But i want **No repeat** on this and full size.

Comment: The background HTML attribute [is deprecated and shouldn't be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). You want to use the [CSS `background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) with [background-repeat: `no-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).

Comment: @misterManSam Worse. That attribute is obsolete, not just deprecated.

Comment: how can i point the css file to my html?

Comment: `michelezsolt` You need to add css **background-attachment: fixed;** property for background fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS for your background image

```
 background: url(Background.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
```

Comment: i write my code in my index.html so this code doesnt work

Comment: Use this CSS for the body of your index.html file

Answer (score 0):

try to add some css :-

```
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
width: 100%;
```

this will solve your problem

Comment: this not solve my problem, I write my code in index.html, not style.css.

my style.css doesnt point to my index.html, i dont know why

Comment: try to provide the path to your style.css in the head using <link> tag. For example:- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="folder-name/file.css"> and in case you are using internal css then write the same css code as i said earlier in the style attribute of the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit CSS by using the following :

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: but my css doesnt work!!! i can write any code in this, i dont know how connect my .html to my css so i can write code in style.css.

Comment: You should add link tag  to your html code and inside the tag but the source to your CSS file and don't forget your html and css file must be in the same location link tag  : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourcss.css ">`

Comment: `Fidaa` In your code there is need to add **background-attachment: fixed;** property for fixed background.

Answer (score 0):

this method is non-conforming, use css.
if you use this code in your email template it may be ok, the background attribute also work on     `<body>, <table>, <td>, <th>`
see snippet below if you want to work inside html body the code.

```html
    <body background="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/14/11/00/nubian-ibex-4764738__340.jpg">
        
     <style>
        body{
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        </style>
    </body>
```

try to use css, html background attribute is non-conforming. see details about it on mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **background-attachment: fixed** property in body style. and set body **min-height:100vh** for cover browser height and *background-position: center;* property to set background image position.

Following snippet has **fixed background** image with *scroll*.

```css
body{
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/07/00/34/heron-4746555_960_720.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
p{
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```